# Next.JS all links and router not working after the build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have a Next JS application, the router links during the dev build work fine, but when I try to make the final build, every time I access the router I get an error: Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

And in console: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

I use  "next": "13.4.19"

I tried to update the version to alpha or lower it a little - it had no effect

The code:

```
    import { useRouter, usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
    
    ...
    
    const handleMenuClick = ({ key }: { key: string }) => {
        router.push(key);
      };
```

Also I did code like this:

```
 <Link href="/finance/bank">{t('AutoBank')}</Link>
```

And got same error here

Stack trace:

596-4a904b5a2b6908f1.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

```
at W (194-4ef1ddd2d8c79d9b.js:1:8991)
at G (194-4ef1ddd2d8c79d9b.js:1:9820)
at t.default (194-4ef1ddd2d8c79d9b.js:252:4926)
at t.default (194-4ef1ddd2d8c79d9b.js:284:4157)
at N (194-4ef1ddd2d8c79d9b.js:22:4547)
at ri (fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9:38931)
at lp (fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9:54222)
at im (fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9:112592)
at oM (fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9:90039)
at fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9:89861
```

window.console.error @ 596-4a904b5a2b6908f1.js:1
r9 @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
n.callback @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
nf @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
nd @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
am @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
aT @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
aT @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
aT @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
aT @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
aT @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
aT @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
aT @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ay @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
(анонимная) @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
oO @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
ok @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
oy @ fd9d1056-3d99af6b23254912.js:9
M @ 596-4a904b5a2b6908f1.js:25

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the error that you see in the browser as well as the relevant part of the code where the error manifests?

Comment: Thank you. Can you edit your question with the stack trace instead of adding it into the comment section and provide the part of the code where it happened as well?